# Animate scatter plot with points of different colors and size each

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have real time data generated by a script which generate x,y1,y2 values where x is sequential and
-10 < y1 < 10  -10 < y2< 10. This is then sent to a .csv file.

I need to display the y1,y2 values in a scatter plot where I only see the last 3 inputs. I also want to update this plot in real time using FuncAnimation.

The idea is that seeing the 3 dots on screen, each value should be recognizable by date.
The last one(i) could be red and big size, the (i-1) yellow and medium size and the(i-2) green and small size.

data_gen.py:

```
import csv
import random
import time
X = 0
Y = 0
Y2 = 0
fieldnames = ["X", "Y", "Y2"]

with open('data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

while True:
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        info = {
            "X": X,
            "Y": Y,
            "Y2": Y2
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(X, Y, Y2)

        X += 1
        Y = random.randint(-10, 10)
        Y2 = random.randint(-10, 10)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Test.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd

def main():

    numframes = 100
    numpoints = 10
    color_data = np.random.random((numframes, numpoints))
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x,y1,y2 = data['X'],data['Y'], data['Y2']

    y1 = y1[-3:]
    y2 = y2[-3:]
    x_ = x.to_numpy()
    y1_ = y1.to_numpy()
    y2_ = y2.to_numpy()
    y1_ = y1_.reshape(-1, 1)
    y2_ = y2_.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_tot= np.hstack((y1_,y2_))

    fig = plt.figure()
    scat = plt.scatter(y1_, y2_,color='red')

    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_xlim(-14, 14)
    axes.set_ylim(-14,14)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot,interval=1000, frames=range(numframes),fargs=(color_data, scat))
    plt.show()

def update_plot(i, data, scat):
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x,y1,y2 = data['X'],data['Y'], data['Y2']
    y1 = y1[-3:]
    y2 = y2[-3:]

    x_ = x.to_numpy()
    y1_ = y1.to_numpy()
    y2_ = y2.to_numpy()
    y1_ = y1_.reshape(-1, 1)
    y2_ = y2_.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_tot= np.hstack((y1_,y2_))


    '''Set de values'''
    scat.set_offsets(y_tot)
    '''Set de color'''
    # scat.set_array(data[i])
    '''Set de tamaño'''
    # scat.set_sizes(scat.get_sizes()*2)
    return scat,

main()
```

I don't know how to proceed. As now, I can display the last 3 updated values generated in the .csv but I can't tell which one is the last.

should I do something like

```
plt.plot(y1_[0],y2_[0],'r',y1_[1],y2_[1],'y',y1_[2],y2_[2],'g')
```

inside the Animation function?

Thank you!

Comment: `scatter(..., c=[0,1,2], s=[25, 100, 4000], cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["green", "yellow", "red"])`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!
I'm trying to put your answer as the right one but I think it's a comment so I can't do it.